# Turtlebot Simulator Package and Rviz Crashing

Tags: simulation, rviz, turtlebot, ros-hydro, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently Running Hydro and the newest version of the turtlebot_simulator Package. Previously teleop commands were not sending but that has been fixed in a newer version I think.

Currently having issues with RViz. It worked prior to the update, now it crashes when point cloud or any sensor is activated. Also, it has never worked with "image"

This was the crash in terminal:

```
Registered event listener change listener:  true 
[rviz-1] process has died [pid 3635, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rviz/rviz -d /opt/ros/hydro/share/turtlebot_rviz_launchers/rviz/robot.rviz __name:=rviz __log:=/home/thesis/.ros/log/c61c9da8-1447-11e3-90c8-0026b97f1590/rviz-1.log].
log file: /home/thesis/.ros/log/c61c9da8-1447-11e3-90c8-0026b97f1590/rviz-1*.log
```

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76270/turtlebot-simulator-package-and-rviz-crashing./) by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2013-09-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-04**:
Hard to tell what's going wrong with that minimal error log. Does the mentioned log file contain any valuable information? Please also state, which launchers and RViz config files you are using.

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-09-04**:
Might be https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/676. What version of RViz are you using? Please post the contents of the log file.

**Comment by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on 2013-09-04**:
My Rviz Version is 1.10.3.
the print out in the logfile rviz-1-stdout.log was not so exciting:
http://pastebin.com/UdZyQ8pb.

Also I'm using the the turtlebot_rviz_launchers v2.1.1

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-09-04**:
Version 2.2.0 is already there. Can you give a try? Also, do you use 32 or 64 bits OS?

**Comment by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on 2013-09-04**:
32 bit OS. Excuse my ignorance but how do I go about updating. My repositories were up to date before I downloaded it, I believe.

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-09-04**:
RViz 1.10.3 had this bug, it's fixed in the most recent release.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-09**:
@Alkaros, if the new RViz version fixes this issue for you, please add a small answer saying so and accept it to close this question. Thx.

**Comment by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on 2013-09-10**:
Updated my Rviz to 1.10.6. Problem is solved. Didn't get a chance to try it till today. Thanks Guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Error using Rviz 1.10.3. Updating to the newer version 1.10.6 solved this issue.

---

Originally posted by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) with karma: 103 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0